# How to return promise from a function that itself uses promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

What I am trying to do is basically

```
function test() {
getSomeValue().then(function (data) {
    //process data
});
}

function getSomeValue() {
//do some long process 
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(result);
});
}

function getSomeOtherValue() {
//do some long process 
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(result);
});
}
```

Function test calls a function that returns a promise and then performs some calculations on the data returned. This part works fine. Now the function `getSomeValue` needs to call another function which also returns a promise. How do I return a promise from `getSomeValue` which also waits for `getSomeOtherValue` to completed.

Let me know if any other information needed.

Comment: You can do the chaining, `.then().then()....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just chain `getSomeOtherValue` inside `getSomeValue`:

```
function getSomeValue() {
    //do some long process 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(result);
    }).then(getSomeOtherValue);
}
```

If you want the order to be switched then:

```
function getSomeValue() {
    //do some long process 
    return getSomeOtherValue().then(function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(result);
        });        
    }
}
```

However, this is for illustration only.  You can design your promises so that you can chain them effectively on a higher level:

```
function test() {
    getSomeOtherValue()
        .then(getSomeValue)
        .then(function (data) {
            //process data
        });
}
```

Comment: actually getSomeOtherValue() needs to be called before. I need data from getSomeOtherValue() and then generate response based on that

Answer (score 2):

to get value from getSomeOtherValue before getSomeValue, just call getSomeOtherValue function first, then chain with another function to process value for getSomeValue, then finally, return the result to the caller (test function)

```
function getSomeValue() {
  //do some long process 
  return getSomeOtherValue().then(function(resultFromSomeOtherValue) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var result = true; //some value after process;
      return resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: added explanation

Answer (score 1):

To wait for the `getSomeOtherValue` function to be resolved, you need to resolve the promise of `getSomeValue` function in the returned promise from the `getSomeOtherValue` function. The code below should hopefully make sense

```
function test() {
getSomeValue().then(function (data) {
    //process data
});
}

function getSomeValue() {
//do some long process 
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  getSomeOtherValue().then(function (data) {
      resolve(result);
  });        
});
}

function getSomeOtherValue() {
//do some long process 
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(result);
});
}
```